referencing an object with multiple names versus one name
In the English language, an object or a concept can have multiple names.
In the specification of a patent application, what are the pros and cons of consistently referring to an object with the same name verses being inconsistent and using the multiple names to refer to the same object?

I am not aware of any "pros" to being inconsistent in a patent specification. The less potential for confusion when reading the specification, the better.
Usually what you describe is not a problem for validity because a person of ordinary skill in the art will know or realize that the same thing is meant by both terms.
On the other hand, I don't see why anyone would knowingly risk introducing such confusion if it is avoidable at drafting time.
